# VS Setup Project set textbox User Interface form programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, setup-project

I'm developing a Windows service Setup, using Visual studio 2015 setup project template. I added a User Interface form where i need to fill the running PC ip at runtime into text box.
Any suggest?

Thanks
O.

Comment: what is 'Windows service Setup', and do you want to add a UI for service?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Installer Setup Project template. I want add custom textbox filed, or be able to change text on runtime, on default UI form available by template.

Comment: you can override the [Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer(v=vs.110).aspx) [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa1y4tz1(v=VS.100).aspx)

Comment: That's right to read text filed value from  UI, but how can i change textfield Text value for a specific form by code? From my understanding Context.Parameters["XXXX"] is only to get data not to set. thanks.